# Window resize condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a responsive image slider, however I keep running into this error:

> error occured: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 422, position 26.

whenever I try to add a condition for window resizing. The problem appears to be coming from the the conditional statement, but how do I resolve it? The script is withing script tags within a xslt file. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
    forcedImageWidth: 700,
    forcedImageHeight: 555,
    separation: 500
  });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 1024){
    $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
      forcedImageWidth: 400,
      forcedImageHeight: 255,
      separation: 100
    });
  }else{alert('hi');}
});
```

Comment: I don't see why you've included an `xslt` tag. Please add information about that or remove the tag. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter because I did not know if that made a difference. The tag is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you re-instantiate the plugin on resize.

But that is not the right way to do.... You have to "reload" it with new options.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Assign a variable to it on instantiation
  var carousel = $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
    forcedImageWidth: 700,
    forcedImageHeight: 555,
    separation: 500
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 1024){
      carousel.reload({
        forcedImageWidth: 400,
        forcedImageHeight: 255,
        separation: 100
      });
    }else{alert('hi');}
  });
});
```

I took the info in [the documentation](https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel/options), where all you have to know about the product you use should be.